# Teamcity 6 and svn+ssh integration problem

Tags: svn, teamcity

I created installation with Teamcity 6.0.2 that uses svn+ssh protocol to obtain sources from linux server.
When I try to connect to linux machine I see exception with log info like below. I created private key with puttygen and exported it as OpenSSH key.
Checkout operation using putty+ TortoiseSVN works without any problems. I have no Banner elem in sshd_config file.

How to resolve that problem?
Linux machine is on Amazon EC2 cloud.

Regards,
Alek

```
[2011-02-27 21:54:29,794]   WARN [loader 1 {id=1}] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error while loading vcs version for root 'svn: svn+ssh://dc-sol/home/svn/platnosci/trunk {id=1}', id=1: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://dc-sol': There was a problem while connecting to dc-sol:22 
[2011-02-27 21:54:29,796]   WARN [loader 1 {id=1}] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error while loading changes for root svn: svn+ssh://dc-sol/home/svn/platnosci/trunk {id=1}, cause: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://dc-sol': There was a problem while connecting to dc-sol:22 
[2011-02-27 21:54:50,962]   WARN [on=editVcsRoot ] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Error occurred in test connection
jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: svn: Cannot connect to 'svn+ssh://dc-sol': There was a problem while connecting to dc-sol:22
 at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.svn.SvnSupport.testConnection(SvnSupport.java:263)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.admin.projects.EditVcsRootsController.doPost(EditVcsRootsController.java:97)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController$1.handleRequest(BaseFormXmlController.java:54)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.AjaxRequestProcessor.processRequest(AjaxRequestProcessor.java:45)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseFormXmlController.doHandle(BaseFormXmlController.java:52)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.BaseController.handleRequestInternal(BaseController.java:73)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.rootDispatcher.TeamCityDispatcherServlet.service(TeamCityDispatcherServlet.java:271)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.web.SetThreadNameFilter.runChainWithModifiedThreadName(SetThreadNameFilter.java:16)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.web.SetThreadNameFilter.doFilter(SetThreadNameFilter.java:3)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at jetbrains.buildServer.web.ResponseFragmentFilter.doFilter(ResponseFragmentFilter.java:9)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same question is covered by TeamCity issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-15598